# Waiting for Ajax called DOM manipulation to finish

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Sorry for the title but I had no idea how to call it.

I got some ajax call function that on success adds some HTML elements to the page:

```
function ajax_submit_append(form_data, url, result, complete) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        success: function(msg) {
              var res = $(msg).filter('span.redirect');
              if($(res).html() != null){
                  window.location.replace($(res).html()); 
                  return false;
              }
            $(result).append(msg);
        },
        complete: complete()
    });
};
```

Function does something on success where the most important is the .append and then this ajax function is called in some button .click function like this:

```
$(function() {
     $("#product_list_add_btn").click(function(e){
         ajax_submit_append(
                    form_data = {
                        product_name: $('.selectpicker option:selected').val(),
                        amount: $('#amount').val()},
                        "<?php echo site_url('admin_panel/new_order/add_product'); ?>",
                        '#add_product_result',
                        calculateSum
                );
         return false; 
         });
});
```

What I want to achieve is that calculateSum function (sums table columns) is called after .append is done via ajax.

For now, when I add calculateSum to ajax complete event it is still called before new row is added to the table with .append

Edit: I present You calculateSum, but I believe there is nothing faulty there.

```
function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    // iterate through each td based on class and add the values
        $(".countit").each(function() {

        var value = $(this).text();
        // add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(value);
        }
    });
    $('#total_price').text(sum);  
    alert("test");
};
```

If I had to guess, I would say its something with click event?

How to fix this?

Comment: I tried with complete event at first as You can see in the code, but didn't get expected result. After adding async: false, no change, alert("test"), always pops up before row is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using jqXHR's done() method:

```
function ajax_submit_append(form_data, url, result, complete) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        success: function(msg) {
              var res = $(msg).filter('span.redirect');
              if($(res).html() != null){
                  window.location.replace($(res).html()); 
                  return false;
              }
            $(result).append(msg);
        }
    }).done(complete);
};
```

Comment: It works fine now. Thank You. By the way, what is the difference between .done and complete event?